# Display All On Sale/Special Price items in Magento

Tags: magento

If you want to set an item "On Sale" in Magento you have to set a "Special Price". Special prices enable you to define a discounted price for a product for a specified period of time.

My question is how can I add a link in my layered navigation to display all my "On Sale"/"Special Price" items.

Thanks

Comment: May be good to cross-post here - http://magento.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

Checkout the following url to do so.

http://www.creativemediagroup.net/creative-media-web-services/magento-blog/27-magento-show-only-special-priced-products-in-a-category

There is a syntax error at Line No 31 approx, so

```
echo '<img src="'.$this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize(135, 135);.'" width="135" height="135" alt=".$this->htmlEscape($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image')).'" title="'.$this->htmlEscape($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image')).'" />
```

replace the above line with the following

```
echo '<img src="'.$this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize(135, 135).'" width="135" height="135" alt="'.$this->htmlEscape($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image')).'" title="'.$this->htmlEscape($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image')).'" />
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment I checked out this page and it's working great for me except I can't get the images to load on the sales page. When I was cutting and pasting the code I did notice an issue towards the end of the code the line that starts with: 'echo '<img src="' was giving me issues and I had to remove it inorder for the sales items to work. do you have any idea how to fix this?

Comment: thanks so much! Was it just the ";" that was causing the error?

Comment: No alt=". should be alt="'.

Answer (score 0):

Call this function:

```
 public function getSpecialProduct(){
 $sql = "SELECT 
            cp.*,
            ea.* 
         FROM 
            catalog_category_product AS cp 
        INNER JOIN 
            catalog_product_entity_decimal AS pei ON 
            pei.entity_id=cp.product_id 
            AND
            pei.attribute_id =76
            AND
            pei.value >0
        NATURAL JOIN 
            eav_attribute AS ea 
        WHERE 
            ea.attribute_code='special_price'
        group by 
            cp.product_id";
    $data = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource') ->getConnection('core_read')->fetchAll($sql);
    foreach($data as $row)
    $arr[] = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->setStoreId($storeId)->load($row['product_id']);
    return $arr; 
}
```